# Como utilizar uma tabela no banco com campos diferentes da camada modelo?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

Por exemplo, eu tenho um tabela onde o campo no banco chamado `COD_CLIENTE`, porém na camada modelo ele é `ID_CLIENTE`, como acesso esse valor sem alterar o nome do no modelo em `VB.net`?

```
Partial Public Class CadastroCliente
    Public Property nome As String
    Public Property contato As String
    Public Property tipo As String
    Public Property ID_CLIENTE As Nullable(Of Integer)

End Class
```

Comment: Qual `framework` de persistência de dados?

Comment: Você usa algum `ORM` ou faz na mão o acesso a dados?

Answer (score 1):

Estranho sua pergunta, porque se for usando somente sql a classe não é mapeada, ou  seja, não reflete seu banco de dados e você pode usar normalmente.

Agora não sei se você está usando algum framework para persistência de dados. Se sim, a maioria deles você pode usar anotações (data annotations) dizendo qual coluna você quer que aquele campo mapeie no banco.

Exemplo:

```
 [Table("cliente")]
 Partial Public Class CadastroCliente
 {
   [Column("cliente_id")]
   Public Property codigo As Int32
 }
```

Comment: Boa, só esta parecendo que a sua esta em c# e não em vb